# Is there anything similar to popup in bootstrap which will still play even though popup is blocked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am just a beginner to UI designing, apologize if its seems silly question. 
I am trying to play a video in a popup in my website when someone hits URL,  but I still want it to play even if browser has blocked the popups.

I tried to play video in home page and it disappears once completed but its not that highlight(refer black box in home page). [image] So I want it look more highlighted by fading the background like in second image.

My focus is to get a video played automatically in the box showed in image(big image), when a home button is clicked. [image]

Can anyone also help me with circular thumb nail as its on this page http://www.paramvah.com/about.html
images keep rotating and also the content keeps changes for each pic.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for this - [How to embed YouTube video in Bootstrap modal](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=play-youtube-video-in-bootstrap-modal)

Comment: No I want it to play automatically without any clicks. Like hit www.pictureshop.in the web page loads and the video plays n disappears.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <div class="video_holder">
      <video id="video_player" controls="controls" poster=""> 
     <source id="video_mp4" src="" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
      </video>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// this line will open your modal when url hits
 $('#myModal').modal('show'); 
 // video will play using this
 $("#video_player")[0].play();
 OR
 $("#video_player")[0].autoplay = true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For youtube only:** The below will display a modal and play video automatically using youtube's `?autoplay=1`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = $("#Video").attr('src');

    $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#Video").attr('src', '');
    });

    $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function () {
        $("#Video").attr('src', url);
    });

    $("#myModal").modal(); //Display modal on load

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example {
        margin: 20px;
    }

    .modal-content iframe {
        margin: 0 auto;
        display: block;
    }
</style>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe id="Video" width="420" height="345" src="http://youtube.com/embed/ZNgvZE0MLeo?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. Only for youtube.

Comment: it works, but main web page is still faded out. As i have a timer for that Div to disappear after video completes.

Comment: Any bootstrap dialog will fade the parent page display. Your second screen shot displays the faded screen for parent page. Is that what you don't want?

Comment: I have updated my code above to remove background fade for main page using CSS.

Comment: Background should be faded until the video plays. once video completes, that div disappears and background gets a life. But updated code is not at all fading the bg.

Comment: Any idea how to make the background transparent after few seconds or after the video completes.